# Collision for intended target is instead colliding along axis only

Tags: processing, collision-detection

I am trying to have an object collide with any of the two obstacles and set its position, however it is registering a collision whenever I pass either of them and in all honesty I am confusing myself a lot and don't know what is wrong at this point. This is the code I am using broken off from everything else:

```
int[] player1;
int[] player2;
int p1width = 50;
int p1height = 50;
int sandbagwidth = 30;
int sandbagheight = 200;
int sand11 =200;
int sand12 = 0;
int sand21 =200;
int sand22 = 400;
void setup(){
  size(1200, 600);
  player1= new int[] {250, 250};

}

void draw(){
  //draw players
  fill(0);
  rect(0,0,width/2,height);
  fill(255,0,0);
  rect(600,0,width/2,height);
  //move players
  fill(255);
  rect(player1[0], player1[1], p1width, p1height);
  if (keyPressed) {
    switch(keyCode) {
    case LEFT:
      player1[0] -=10;
      break;
    case RIGHT:
      player1[0] +=10;
      break;
    case UP:
      player1[1] -=10;
      break;
    case DOWN:
      player1[1] +=10;
      break;
    }
  }



   if(player1[0]+25>1150){
     player1[0]-=25;
   }
   if(player1[0]-25<0){
     player1[0]+=50;
   }


   if(player1[1]+25>550){
     player1[1]-=25;
   }
   if(player1[1]-25<0){
     player1[1]+=50;
   }

   //COLLISION
   fill(0,255,0);
   rect(sand11, sand12, sandbagwidth, sandbagheight);
   fill(0,255,0);
   rect(sand21, sand22, sandbagwidth, sandbagheight);
   if(player1[0] + p1width/2 > sand11 -  sandbagwidth/2
    && player1[0] - p1width/2 < sand11 + sandbagwidth/2
    && player1[1] + p1height/2 > sand12 - sandbagheight/2
    && player1[1] - p1height/2 < sand12 + sandbagheight/2){
     player1[0]=220;
     player1[1]=250;
    }

    if(player1[0] + p1width/2 > sand21 - sandbagwidth-25
    && player1[0] - p1width/2 < sand21 + sandbagwidth-25
    && player1[1] + p1height/2 > sand22 - sandbagheight-25
    && player1[1] - p1height/2 < sand22 + sandbagheight-25){
     player1[0]=50;
     player1[1]=50;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you're using `player1`, `sandXX`, etc. as the top-left corners when drawing, but as the centre when calculating collisions (unless you have a `rectMode` call in the code you haven't included). This could easily cause your bug - try to pass the bottom sandbag at the bottom, even though there is no visible gap there.

Nitpick: you also switch between constants and calculated values; this is going to bite you in the long run, even if it works here. For example, `rect(600,0,width/2,height)` should probably be `rect(width/2,0,width/2,height)`. `player1[0]=220` in the collision response code is an even better candidate for being replaced with calculations based on your variables.

Comment: This worked perfectly, after using rectMode(CENTER) and adjusting the positions of objects based on the new rectMode. But I have a question what do u mean by player1[0]=220 is better, I have it working but if I remove player[1] repositioning it doesn't work so I am not sure what you mean

Comment: I mean, where did you get the value 220 from? From sand11 plus some combination of player width and sandbag width, or via some other means? You should put that actual calculation in, rather than just the value "220", otherwise if you change the values you are likely to end up with another bug.